# How to connect an Azure webjob/appservice to an Azure remote database programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I've created a WebJob based on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started

The WebJob is there to automatically create an SQLite database and then populate the database with data from one of our Azure Databases. The Azure Databases all have the same structure. To do the syncing, I'm using Microsoft.Datasync.Client & Microsoft.Datasync.Client.SQLiteStore based on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/winui/

&

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/data-sync

The problem I'm having is that in the quickstart example (two links up from here), the Azure database is defined in Service Dependencies using the publish settings interface. That process sets up a single database, which presumably the local SQLite DB `stor`e and `client` variables will automagically connect to.

Because my database names will vary, I need help with connecting the application to the correct Azure database via code within my DB Creation method below so that the proper Azure database will populate the new SQLite database. Note that the `message` parameter in the webjob queue trigger method contains the database name, which is passed to the SQLite DB creation method.

Queue trigger:

```
    public static void ProcessQueue([QueueTrigger("queue_trigger")] string message, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            if (message.StartsWith("[DB_CREATION]_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                message = message.Replace("[DB_CREATION]_", "");

                ProcessSqliteDbCreation(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in connection establishment: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

SQLite DB Creation Method and Supporting Methods:

```
    private static void ProcessSqliteDbCreation(string azureDBName)
    {
        //Create local dir
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(_DefaultLocalDBPath);

        //get projectdbnameon mobile using projectdbname
        var sqlLiteDBName = GetProjectDbNameOnMobile(azureDBName);

        // Set path of database file
        string DbFile = $"{_DefaultLocalDBPath}{sqlLiteDBName}_{Guid.NewGuid()}.db"; 

        // Create database file
        File.WriteAllBytes(DbFile, new byte[0]);

        string offlineConnectionString = new UriBuilder { Scheme = "file", Path = DbFile, Query = "?mode=rwc" }.Uri.ToString();
        var store = new OfflineSQLiteStore(offlineConnectionString); //"file:" is required

        // Define structure of all tables of database
        DefineTables(store); 

        var options = new DatasyncClientOptions
        {
            HttpPipeline = new DelegatingHandler[] { new DbNameHandler(azureDBName) },
            OfflineStore = store,
            SerializerSettings = new Microsoft.Datasync.Client.Serialization.DatasyncSerializerSettings()
            {
                CamelCasePropertyNames = false,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
            },
        };
        var client = new DatasyncClient(aimWebUtilityUrl, options);

        client.InitializeOfflineStoreAsync();

        // Method for pulling data from Azure DB to new SQLite DB
        KeepPulling(client); //SEE METHOD BELOW

        // Upload created database file on blob storage
        if (File.Exists(DbFile)) CreateAndUploadDbZip(sqlLiteDBName, DbFile);
    }

    public static void KeepPulling(DatasyncClient client)
    {
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
        Parallel.Invoke(po,

            async () => await PullOneAsync<Table1>(client), //SEE METHOD BELOW
            async () => await PullOneAsync<Table2>(client)
            );
    }

    // Pull data from server one by one 
    static async Task PullOneAsync<T>(DatasyncClient client)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<TableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

        try
        {
            var table = client.GetOfflineTable<T>();
            table.PullItemsAsync(table.CreateQuery()).Wait(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE (SEE ERROR BELOW)
        }
        catch (PushFailedException exc)
        {
            if (exc.PushResult != null) syncErrors = (ReadOnlyCollection<TableOperationError>)exc.PushResult.Errors;
        }

        // Simple error/conflict handling
        if (syncErrors != null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Error received is below. The error occurs at the pull command (see comment in code above), which is not surprising because there is no Azure database connection. I need to add a connection using the provided database name. Error is included below just in case it is helpful somehow:

> System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=One or more
> errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see
> inner exception.)   Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
> ...Functions.d__13`1.MoveNext()
> in
> D:...\Functions.cs:line
> 580    at
> ...Functions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> in
> D:...\Functions.cs:line
> 412
>
> Inner Exception 1: HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not
> be established, see inner exception.
>
> Inner Exception 2: AuthenticationException: Authentication failed
> because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'.
>
> Inner Exception 3: Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected
> or badly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *one of our Azure databases*, I'm assuming you have server/database1, server/database2. If so, then using the backend service example from [How to use the ASP.NET Core backend server SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/server/dotnet-core), the service dependency isn't an issue. You will have a [TableController](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/blob/main/samples/TodoApp/TodoAppService.NET6/Controllers/TodoItemController.cs) for each database. To make sure you the web job is pulling they sync data from the proper database, you can include the table endpoint as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/client/dotnet#options).

```cs
var options = new DatasyncClientOptions
{
    ...
    TableEndpointResolver = (table) => $"/tables/{tableName.ToLowerInvariant()}",
};
```

The main gist is the client needs to connect to the correct table controller in order to sync data.

But I don't think the issue is with the code, I think it's more about the connection between the web job and the backend server. Looking at the [DatasyncClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/blob/50fc5a6a7b6eac443bada7a41a67e5ed3fb1af03/sdk/dotnet/src/Microsoft.Datasync.Client/DatasyncClient.cs#L120C3-L120C3), I would say there's a misconfiguration with your app service. By default, its underlying client sends `"3.0.0"` as the `ProtocolVersion` but the inner exception says it's malformed. Could be a Tls configuration or cipher suite issue, difficult to say. Running a ***Network Trace*** in ***Diagnose and solve problems*** blade could yield better information.

---

**EDIT 2023 June 26**

To have the web job "drive" offline setup, your backend service still needs to "host" the data for offline sync. The way I would go about it is when the queue message contains the database the app will use, the web job will only construct uri string and return it back the [client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/blob/main/samples/Net7Maui/TodoMauiApp/MainPage.xaml.cs). But remember, you can either hosts multiple databases under one backend service or one backend service per database, choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I have a few of questions that probably won't fit into a comment. Please forgive, as we are migrating from AppFramework to WinUI3 and Azure, so much of this is new. I'll start with TableEndpointResolver. I read the page in your link, but I might have a semantics issue. Where is the db identified, and how is a connection string established? is the "/tables/" in the EnpointResolver the database name? How about credentials?

Comment: Second question: Our WinUI3 app is using Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core... for our models, context, etc.. For normal remote (Azure) database read/write, the context's connection string is appended with the database name being used. We cannot hard-code any database name because they are being added through the UI of the application by app users. The webjob in my question uses those EF models to define the OffLineSQLiteStore. Having a TableController for each database is not possible. The thrust of my question is how to give the DB name for SQLite sync as we do for read/write operation.

Comment: The `TableController` is decorated with a `[Route]` that determines the endpoint. I think "Mobile app" follows more of an odata methodology so the template will decorate /table/{resource}. The connection string is established in the server hosting project that has your table controllers. Credentials is based on how the backend server project is configured; each Get Started section has an Add Authentication section.

Comment: OK. I think the missing piece was the backend service. I have an older example of one where the database name is sent through HTTP headers. I was hoping for a way to sync an SQLite on a local desktop using our current WinUI3 desktop app Architecture, but I'm getting the feeling the syncing needs to be done using the ASP.NET Core back-end service per the link you provided, correct? Anyhow, I'll mark the question as answered. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I updated my answer on how I would approach the back-end service portion given your scenario. I don't think there's anything wrong with the approach, but I don't see particularly see the leverage the web job.

Comment: I just saw your most recent comment. The WinUI3 desktop app will do an offline sync with your back-end service. It's just an API wrapped similar to ODATA. The samples you want to reference is the [client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/tree/main/samples/TodoApp/TodoApp.WinUI) and the [back-end web api](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/tree/main/samples/TodoApp/TodoAppService.NET6).